# Show linear bounded automata accepting w is PSPACE-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions, space-complexity

```
ALBA={⟨M;w⟩ | M is linear bounded automata which accepts input w}
```

Show that ALBA is PSPACE-complete.

How I would try to solve it...

1. We need to prove ALBA belongs to PSPACE. So I would construct TM A which accepts <M;w>. Simulate M till qng^n steps or when it halts. If it halts: Accept <M,w> if M accepts w, otherwise reject.
   How would be space complexity? I would say it will need n (=size of the tape) so space complexity should be O(n) and then ALBA belongs to PSPACE. Is it correct?
2. We need to do reduction from TQBH to ALBA to prove that ALBA is NP hard, but I have no idea how to do it. How should this reduction be done? TQBF must be 1 if ALBA accepts w i guess, but dont know how to show the proof...

Comment: In part 2, don't try a reduction from TQBF. Use the definition of PSPACE instead.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus What do you mean "definition of PSPACE"? Would you please give me a little bit more information?

Comment: Given a Turing machine $T$ using space $p(n)$ (for some polynomial $p$) and an input $x$, determine whether $T$ accepts $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Savitch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem) shows that PSPACE=NPSPACE, which immediately implies that ALBA is in PSPACE.

In the other direction, suppose that $L$ is a language in PSPACE. Thus $L$ is accepted by some machine that uses space $p(n)$. We can construct another machine $L'$ which accepts an input $(x,y)$, erases $y$, and simulates $L$ on $x$. We can reduce $L$ to ALBA by mapping $L$ to $L'$ and $x$ to $(x,0^{p(|x|)})$.

Comment: thanks. I dont still understand how the reduction works. We have TM L in space p(n). Then TM L′ which accepts (x,y) = x is the the string which is input to M? (linear bounded automata) and y is what? Can you give me example, how these two Turing machines work together? Also, what is 0p(|x|)? p is some function polynomal, x is size of input x and 0 is what?

Comment: Here $0$ is the letter zero and $0^n$ is the letter zero repeated $n$ times.

Comment: and what is "y"? how the second machine works? it accepts x and y and do what with it? and why the second machine has the second argument Oto(p(x)?

Comment: Here $y$ is a dummy input, whose sole purpose is to pad the input to make it large enough.

Comment: I’m not including all the details since it’s an exercise.

Comment: so basically L′ should prepare the input for L? So L′ changes x according to y and then the changed x is used as input to L? And why there must be padding? large enough means that x must be big as size of the tape of M?

Comment: The role of $y$ is to pad the input, so that an algorithm which needs space $|x|^2$ will only need space $|(x,y)|$.

Comment: and why is there padding for? I am sorry, but i still dont understand the logic behind it... how does y change x? adds 0 where?

Comment: You have a machine using space $n^2$. You want to simulate it on a machine that is only allowed to use space $n$. The solution is to pad the original input of length $n$ to length $n^2$. This is a standard technique in complexity theory.

Comment: and how do you know that machine L is using space n^2?

Comment: It uses polynomial space, by definition of PSPACE. I gave $n^2$ just as an example.

Comment: thank you. So the whole idea is: TM L uses n^2 (space) and we create L′ which only make input of length n to n^2). And if L accepts w then M (LBA) also accepts input w. Do I understand it right? But how does accepting word w of size n^2 prove that ALBA also accepts its input?

Comment: Right, that's the idea. You'll have to fill in the blanks on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please also give me idea why this should be O(log n) reduction? I think that it is connected with the padding of the input, but I would say it is O(n) not O(log n)...

Comment: You can compute the output using logarithmic space.

Comment: and why you can compute it with log space and not n space?

Comment: You’ll have to work it out. Make sure that you understand how logspace computation works.

Comment: Briefly, you can compute $|x|$ and $p(|x|)$ on the work tape, and then you just copy the input and add $p(|x|)$ many zeroes.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot to understand it :)